# partition of a digraph vertices

Tags: graph-theory

following the question [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116239/mice-and-their-relations). I have a stronger conjecture:

Given a Digraph G. Prove that if the maximum [independence set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in G is of order m then there are m disjoint paths in G (i.e. m paths with no common vertex) s.t. the union of the vertices of the m paths is the set of vertices of G.

Does anybody know of a proof or a counter example?

by the way: if we assume G is a graph and not a digraph the theorem is indeed correct and easy to prove.

Comment: @Casteels Thanks. I'll edit regarding your remarks. But obviously m is the order of a subgraph so it is not greater then the order of G

Comment: This is the Gallai–Milgram theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Prove, and in fact the paths may be assumed to be vertex-disjoint:** Let $\cal{P}$ be a set of $m$ or fewer vertex-disjoint paths that covers the largest number of vertices of $G$. If every vertex is in a path in $\cal{P}$ already then we are done, so let us now assume that there is a vertex $v$ that is not in any path in $\cal{P}$.

1. If there is a vertex $v$ that is not in any path in $\cal{P}$, then we claim that $\cal{P}$ has exactly $m$ paths $P_1,P_2,\ldots, P_m$. Indeed, otherwise for any vertex $v$ not covered by a path in $\cal{P}$, if we add the singleton path $\{v\}$ to $\cal{P}$, then there will still be no more than $m$ vertex-disjoint paths that cover the additional vertex $v$.
2. If there is a vertex $v$ not covered by a path in $\cal{P}$, then writing $\cal{P}=\{P_1,P_2, \ldots, P_m\}$, the following is true: For each $i=1,2,\ldots, m$, let $v_i$ be an endpoint of $P_i$. Then $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_m\}$ form an independent set in $G$. Indeed, if $v_iv_k$ is an edge in $G$, then replace the two paths $P_i$ and $P_k$ in $\cal{P}$ with the single path $P_i+\{v_iv_k\}+P_k$ i.e., $P_i$ and $P_k$ connected by the edge $v_iv_k$. The  result will be a collection of $m-1$ vertex-disjoint paths that cover just as many paths as $\cal{P}$, and by 1 above, that cannot be.

We then partition into $2$ remaining cases:

**Case 1: $v$ is adjacent to a vertex $v'$ that is an endpoint of a path $P' \in \cal{P}$.** Then $\cal{P}$ is not a set of $m$ or fewer paths that covers the largest number of vertices of $G$ after all; indeed, $P' \in \cal{P}$ can be replaced with $P'+\{vv'\}$, and the resulting collection still has the same number of paths that remain vertex-disjoint, but that cover the additional vertex $v$.

**Case 2: $v$ is not adjacent in $G$ to any endpoint of a path in $\cal{P}$** Then by 1. above, $\cal{P}$ consists of exactly $m$ paths $P_1,\ldots, P_m$, and by 2. above, $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_m\}$ form an independent set in $G$, where $v_i$ is any endpoint of $P_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots, m$. However, that $v$ is not adjacent in $G$ to any endpoint of a path in $\cal{P}$ implies that $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_m,v\}$ is an independent set in $G$ with $m+1$ vertices. This contradicts the fact that a maximum-cardinality independent set in $G$ has only $m$ vertices.